# Python3 Recursivley Sum Digits of an Integer

Tags: python, recursion, python-3.x

I need help implementing a function that will take the digits of an integer and sum them together. As long as the sumDigits function implements recursion, it is valid, and the main function must be left as is. I will include a template below:

```
def sumdigits(value): 
    #recursively sum digits 

def main():
    number=int(input(“Enter a number :  ”))
    print(sumdigits(number))

main()
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A very short version:

```py
def sumdigits(value):
    return value and (value % 10 + sumdigits(value // 10))
```

The `value and` part makes it return zero rather than recurse infinitely once it gets past the last digit.

The `value % 10` part gets the last digit (the "ones" place).

The `sumdigits(value // 10)` gets the sum of all of the digits except the last digit

`//` is integer division, throwing away the fractional part of the result for you automatically.

Comment: [tail-recursive variant `return sumdigits(value // 10, total + value % 10) if value != 0 else total`](http://ideone.com/pjs1TG)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian What are the advantages of that (in Python)? Also, for this particular case, he may not be allowed to change the function signature.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the explanation!

Comment: @agf: it is an addition to your answer, not a critique. In Python a non-recursive solution such as `sum(map(int, str(number)))` would be used (the question is a homework about recursion, not Python)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I didn't take it as a critique; I was just hoping you'd flesh out your comment since you linked to code without context.

Comment: [figures 1.3 and 1.4 from SICP might explain the difference](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.1)